# Laravel Vue SPA: How can the prop which is an array retrieved by axios be passed to a child component?

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, axios

Laravel Vue SPA: How can the prop which is an array retrieved by `axios` be passed to a child component?

The json object is correctly available at `somedomain.com/channellist`.
It is then retrieved by `axios`, and then passed to a child component.

How can it be passed to the child component so that `activeChannel` is properly rendered?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Vue child component:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">      
             <p>{{ activeChannel }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
 
    props: ['channels'],

    data() {
            return {
            
            activeChannel: this.channels[0].id,
           
        }   
    },
   
   methods: {
    
        
    },
    
   components: {
     
   },
    
   created() {
     
  }
}
</script>
<style>
    #app {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }

    .heading h1 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Vue parent component:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">      
       <vue-chat :channels="channels"></vue-chat>
       <div v-for="channel in channels" :key="channel.id">
          <label>Channel Name</label>
          <input type="text" readonly :value="channel.name">
          <br>
          <label>Channel Name</label>
          <input type="text" readonly :value="channel.created_at">
       </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
 
    data() {
      return {
        
        channels: [],
        
      }
    },
   
   methods: {
    
        getChannels(){
            this.loading = true
            var url = "/channellist"
                
            axios
              .get(url)
              .then(response => (this.channels = response.data.channels))
            },     
    },
    
    watch: {

    },
    
    components: {
     
    },
    
    created() {
     
      this.getChannels()
   
     }
  }
</script>
<style>
    #app {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }

    .heading h1 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
```

json object returned from Laravel at `somedomain.com/channellist`:

```
{"channels":[{"id":1,"name":"channel 1","created_at":"2020-07-10T06:03:14.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-10T06:03:14.000000Z"},{"id":2,"name":"channel 2","created_at":"2020-07-10T06:03:14.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-10T06:03:14.000000Z"},{"id":3,"name":"channel 3","created_at":"2020-07-10T06:03:14.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-10T06:03:14.000000Z"}]}
```

Comment: The code you pasted should work... Which problem are you having?

Comment: In the browser console there is an error for the child component: `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: this.channels[0] is undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is before the request get solved. Before that moment, you are passing an empty array as prop. So calling `channels[0].id` results in the

> TypeError: this.channels[0] is undefined

error, because there is no index 0 in channels.

One **fast fix** would be

```
   <vue-chat v-if="channels.length && channels[0].id" 
             :channels="channels">
    </vue-chat>
```

but a **more robust** solution is to create a **[watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)** on your child component that will set the desired value when the prop become available.

Hope this helps!